# how to give class name using php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add *class* like this "`class' => 'form-control'` in this but it is not working.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'SupplierAddress',
    'value' => set_value('SupplierAddress'),
    'id'=>'SupplierAddress',  
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'required' => 'true'
);

echo form_input($data);
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no error occurs , class is not working @ dparoli

Comment: updating code formatting with line breaks for readability

Comment: This is not working because of `form_input` function is not making any output. If you want us to check this code, please bring the source of `set_value` and `form_input` functions.